# How to detect which property is selected/clicked

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, angular6

I'm trying to detect which property is selected/clicked out of ngFor , which comes from a REST API.

I want to get which property(broker.username) is selected out of others

```
<div class="list-group">
    <ul *ngFor="let broker of brokers">
        <li class="broker_list"> <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="text-align: center;">{{broker.username}}</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

this is the REST call

```
[
    { id: 1, username: "PersonA"},
    { id: 2, username: "PersonB"}
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by selected? On which a user clicked?

Comment: yes, which item is clicked, out of other items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use event handler on [anchor tag](https://angular.io/guide/user-input) like this:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <ul *ngFor="let broker of brokers">
        <li class="broker_list">
            <a (click)="onSelect(broker)" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="text-align: center;"> {{ broker.username }}</a>
        </li> 
    </ul>

</div>
```

Within your component add method:

```
@Component({ })
class XYZ {
    // ... some code

    public onSelect(broker) {
        // Do what you need with broker?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the broker directly in the method, like this

```
<div class="list-group">
     <ul *ngFor="let broker of brokers">
          <li class="broker_list"> <a href="#" (click)="setBroker(broker)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="text-align: center;">{{broker.username}}</a></li> 
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, one of those would be to do something like this.

1) Add click handler on `a` tag:

```
<div class="list-group">
          <ul *ngFor="let broker of brokers">
              <li class="broker_list"> <a href="#" (click)="selected(broker.username)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="text-align: center;">{{broker.username}}</a></li> 
            </ul>

  </div>
```

2) Add method to component:

```
selected(brokerName: string) {
  console.log(brokerName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a (click) property that calls a function, which takes a broker as a parameter. You can then access the username of that broker.

```
<a href="#" (click)="handleBrokerClicked(broker)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="text-align: center;">{{broker.username}}</a>
```

The a tag should be able to know what the current broker is, since it is inside the *ngFor.